# How to take the latitude and longitude data for each row of data frame and assign corresponding population density?

Tags: r, ggplot2, qualtrics, geography, rworldmap

New to R. I have a dataset of survey respondents (from Qualtrics). Looking for a way to take latitude and longitude data for each entry and assign population density to survey respondents.

Is there any sort of package or method that can tell me the population density at geographic coordinates?  I do not have the population density information-- I'm looking to find that data. Is this something that is possible in R?

Thank you so much!! I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I had a similar problem and received a nice answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040532/colouring-density-of-stat-density2d-in-ggplot-with-ggmap

Comment: Do you have the population density information already, or are you just looking to get the data on population density?

Comment: Hey @chemdork123, I do not have the population density information-- I'm looking to find that data.

Comment: Then search available datasets that are typically posted by governmental census bureaus.  For example [here's where you can get some datasets for US population statistics](https://www.census.gov/data/datasets/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-state-total.html).  They are not going to be listed by lattitude and longitude, but often you get breakdowns by county within a state (at least you can for the US).  Merge datasets based on that and you can probably draw a useable map (if that's your final goal).